# DNS a specific page to other server

Tags: php, dns, server

If I had a website hosted on server A, but for whatever reason I want to host a specific page of that website on another server (with different I.P. addresses), as such:

```
website.com on server A
website.com/about on Server A
website.com/contact on Server B
```

Is there a way with DNS that you can specifically point an individual page to an alternate server?

Furthermore, if this is possible, would it require special setup on the Server B, or could you essentially create the website with only the "contact" page and it would work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot specify DNS entries based on paths. DNS only handles the name to address translation, it touches nothing and sees nothing with the path. You can however setup your server to reverse proxy to the other server on that URL.

Comment: Hint: The hostname is part of the URL.

Comment: Why would you host specific pages on a different webserver..? If you want to fetch data from a database on Server B, you should create an API or whatever.

Comment: try `nslookup google.com/arglebargle` for your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when your browser sends a DNS server a query for `website.com`, what you want that DNS server to do is to send different answers depending on what your browser intends to use the answer for later on.

I hope you can see yourself that this is impossible. The DNS server simply stores data for names. It has no idea what kind of programs are asking it questions, nor can it predict the future.

That you are asking this question here indicates that you are in some way working with websites. If you are, you *really* should read up on what the various parts of a URL mean, and what happens when a browser fetches a web page.

Comment: Thank's for your response.

I had fairly high expectations that it would be impossible, but didn't want to be ignorant enough to presume I knew everything, so thought I would check anyway.